# Case on PHP SQL queries different from case on MySQL database. Cannot use lower_case_table_names = 1

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I'm having an issue with a website I wrote in PHP on a WAMP server on Windows, issue is, it's now being deployed on a Linux server. The site is quite big and I've done all my queries this way in all caps:

```
"SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE"
```

And most of the tables/columns in the database use a different case (For example, Column).

I cannot use `lower_case_table_name=1` since there are other PHP websites on the server that would be affected negatively. Is there a way for me to switch all of my database's tables and columns into upper case?

Comment: Why not just use all lowercase table names as is pretty much the standard convention in SQL? Column names aren't a problem as these are case-insensitive.

Comment: Because I'd have to go and change every single request in 40 different PHP files.

Comment: That is what global search/replace is for.  40 files is a small project.

Comment: The 40 files fetch things from 30 different tables. I'm just gonna go and do it manually, It's going to be faster than arguing about it.

Comment: You have been given some usable solutions below. I was just suggesting sticking with all lowercase for code potability (and it really helps with readability of your SQL in your code when the SQL keywords are upper case and the database objects are lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have change the names of `columns` and `tables` if you database is not so huge you can try 
this

```
select concat('rename table ', column_name, ' to ' , lower(column_name) , ';') 
from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'your_schema_name';
```

and rename or change the `case` for more help [see](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) and [lower_case_table_names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names)

Comment: I have about 30 tables. Some of them only have two-three fields, but some of them have up to ten. I guess I just have to get to work.

Comment: yes you have to if u cannot set `lower_case_table_names` variable on server

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE yourtablename RENAME TO YOURTABLENAME;